# Can you recommend a kick-ass user interface for a multiple-choice quiz?

Tags: android, choices

I am working on a quiz app, and want to give it a kick-ass UI. I have this so far:

[image: sample quiz UI]

That is, if you choose the wrong answer, it is highlighted with red, and the correct answer is always highlighted with green. With the arrow buttons you can browse the questions and answer them anytime.

Q1: how would you criticize this UI? (looks boring? lacks imagination? ...)

Q2: can you point me to a kick-ass quiz UI you love and I can learn from?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't the site to get reviews of your interface - that provides no benefit to anyone other than yourself. We are a Q&A site that provides a repository for questions and answers that people can search for to find answers to their UX problems. Also, requesting examples of 'X' just solicits poll type responses, no actual answers that solve the problem.

Comment: The kilobyte question is terrible. "1000 bytes" is **not** wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The colors are a bit bland, and the interface looks like it leaves room for fat-finger errors.  I think something like this: http://puu.sh/1TmRA would relieve that pain significantly, especially if the selected answer were highlighted in grey on the first tap and had to be tapped again to be submitted.